# How to open file and use each line as a variable?

Tags: python, python-2.7, twython

I'm using Twython to follow someone and the code below is tested and works:

```
twitter = Twython(app_key, app_secret, oauth_token, oauth_token_secret)
twitter.create_friendship(screen_name="TWITTERHANDLEHERE")
```

So I have a `txt` file in the same directory as the Python file. The file holds a list of Twitter names, each on a separate line. The idea is that the program would issue the command for each line and follow everyone down the list. I know I can use:

```
f = open("test.txt","r")
print f.read()
```

to read the names from the file, but I'm not sure how I would feed the data from each line into the `create_friendship`.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is execute the same command for each user in your text file you can just build the command with a for loop.

```
twitter = Twython(app_key, app_secret, oauth_token, oauth_token_secret)
with open('test.txt', 'r') as users_file:
    for user in users_file:
        twitter.create_friendship(screen_name=user)
```

Comment: you should use `user.rstrip()`, if you don't want the newline character

Comment: OP can also just do `user.strip()` it's the same thing.